# Random effect for handling multiple (but varying) outcomes per individual

Tags: regression, mixed-model, modeling, random-effects-model, independence

I have a dataset where I have at least one clinical measurement for 1000 individuals, but for a subset I have more than measurement. These are patients with a disease that can temporally become more or less severe, so multiple clinical measurements may reflect periods of increased or decreased severity. Additionally, how many extra measurements an individual can have varies (some may have 2 measurements, others 3, etc). My independent variable is a genetic marker, which would be the same for individuals with multiple clinical measurements.

I would like to keep all clinical measurements, however they are clearly not all independent of one another. I am thinking of using a random effect to account for this. Would I create a sparse design matrix where I just code clinical measurements from the same individuals as '1' and everything else in the rows for that individual as '0'?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use the genetic marker presence to predict the clinical measurements?

You can use a multilevel regression to do this even though some participants only have one observation. To do this, organize your data into long format and create an ID variable, like this (id denotes an individual, gmark is genetic marker, I assumed it is yes/no variable, and y is the clinical observation, I assumed it was a continuous variable):

```
  id gmark  y
  1   yes  2.73023175
  1   yes -0.73526896
  1   yes -0.86780859
  2    no -0.60646945
  2    no -0.02059873
  2    no -0.21054050
  3   yes -0.83122649
  3   yes -1.37551132
  3   yes  1.30495183
```

The multilevel regression code in R would be:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

model<-lmer(y ~ (1|id)+gmark, data=dataset)
```

Edit. though you'd want to code the genetic marker as 1 and 0 so you get interpretable estimates.

An alternative might be single-level regression with clustered standard errors (see here: https://www.statisticshowto.com/clustered-standard-errors/ )

Comment: great, thank you, think this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

The details of how you run the random effect model will depend on what model exactly you have in mind. For a random intercept model, you might simply make the constant a function of the id variable, i.e. `alpha[id]`. The detail of how to do that will depend on the software you use to implement this, of course.